# How to create circle image and text Which are complementary to each other in bootstrap or pure css?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I create a sample like this image:

[image]

---

Description: The `circle` is an `image` and each of those `rectangles` are `texts` (Each of them is a line of text).

The image is circled using `bootstrap` `.image-circle`, so I want to do this compatible with `bootstrap`, if there is no exist any `bootstrap` solution please give a `pure css` solution.

Thanks for your contributions.

Comment: How do you expect each line of text to be the right length?

Comment: @aw04 , text length is not important. My main purpose in the padding on the beginning of each line (near the circle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is. You are in luck I love drawing with CSS lol

```
.bars{
  margin-top: 26px;
  position:absolute;
  max-width:350px;
}

.bar{
  background:#1E8CBF;
  height:30px;
  width:250px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.circle{
  background:#1E8CBF;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width:200px;
  height: 200px;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  left:220px;
  top:0;
  border:20px solid #fff
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="bars">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="circle">
      </div>  
</div>
```

Here is the [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yegBbZ)

Comment: You are a great artist, I love your painting ;).